# Lower estimate using Taylor theorem

Tags: real-analysis

Given a twice differentiable function on $[-1,1]$ with $f(0)=0$ and $f(\epsilon)\leq 0$ for $\epsilon\in[-1,1]$. There is a claim that one can use taylor's theorem to proof the following $$0\geq f(1)\geq \inf_{\epsilon\in[0,1]}\frac{\epsilon^2}{2}f''(\epsilon)$$.

However I cannot see how this inequality is true. I have found out that $f'(0)=0$. How should I use the taylor theorem? Around which point shall I develop?

Any hint would be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the formula for the remainder of a Taylor series (centered at 0, in this case)?

Comment: @DougM Something with order of $\epsilon^2$? Or do you ask for an explicit expression of the remainder?

Comment: Doug was aiming at an explicit expression. Namely the Lagrange form of the remainder in this case.

Comment: @DanielFischer sorry this bound is then obvious. The term on the right is always smaller than the remainder of $f(1)$ developed at 0 after 1 term using Lagrange expression.

Comment: Something doesn't look right to me in the above expression.

Comment: @copper.hat what do you mean.

Comment: @quallenjäger: I have not yet convinced myself that it is correct :-). It seems like $f''$ could 'dive' close to 0 and then recover so that the $\inf$ does not reflect the value of $f$.

Comment: @copper.hat but it is a lower bound. Does it really matter?

Comment: Yes, the $f''$ is 'mollified' by the $\epsilon^2$ term so (I am guessing) $f$ could have a lower value than estimated by the above. (I could be way off base. It just triggers my 'spidey' sense.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an unsatisfactory counter example:

Let $h_n$ ('Hessian') be given by the graph created by joining the following points:
$(-1,0), (0, 0), ({1 \over n}, -4), ({1 \over 4}-{1 \over n},-4), ({1 \over 4}, 0), (1,0)$.

Let
$g_n(x) = \int_{-1}^x h_n(t)dt$, $f_n(x) = \int_{-1}^x g_n(t)dt$.

We see that $f_n$ is $C^2$, $f_n(x) \le 0$, $f_n(0) = 0$.

Note that $h_n(x) \downarrow -4 \cdot 1_{(0,{1 \over 4})}(x)$, $g_n(x) \downarrow -4x \cdot 1_{(0,{1 \over 4})}(x)-1_{[{1 \over 4},1]}(x)$, and
$f_n(x) \downarrow -2x^2 \cdot 1_{(0,{1 \over 4})}(x)-(x-{1 \over 8})\cdot 1_{[{1 \over 4},1]}(x)$.

In particular, $f_n(1) \to -{7\over 8}$.

However, $x^2 h_n(x) \ge - 4 x^2 \cdot 1_{(0,{1 \over 4})}(x)$, and so
$\inf_{x \in [0,1]} {1 \over 2} x^2 h_n(x) \ge -{1 \over 8}$.